# Angular add directives after angular bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I'm using ngMeteor (Angular for Meteor) and I was successful in adding `Controllers`, `Filters`, `Services` using their corresponding providers (e.g `$controllerProvider` and function `register()` for controllers). Is there a counter part for doing so with directives? I can't find anything like `$directiveProvider`

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around with getting Angular to load everything dynamically, and I finally got most of it to work. [Wes Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2656063/wes-reid) is correct. You have to use `$compileProvider`, but it requires a bit more than that. I was unable to get this to work, unless I get the `$compileProvider` in `config`, that is *during bootstrapping*. I bet, there are other ways. For example, you can probably also get it through the `$injector` service etc.

[Here is my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bf8m/33/):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(function($controllerProvider, $compileProvider) {
    // see page 12 of:
    //    http://www.slideshare.net/nirkaufman/angularjs-lazy-loading-techniques
    app.lazyController = $controllerProvider.register;

    // see: http://jsfiddle.net/8Bf8m/33/
    app.lazyDirective = $compileProvider.directive;
});

// ... time passes ...

app.lazyDirective('clickMe', function () { return {
    link : function (scope, element) {
        element.bind('click', function () {
            alert('Clicked: ' + element.text());
        });
    },
};});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the $compileProvider.

```
$compileProvider.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // link function body
  };
});
```